# Matrix computation from a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have no idea how to go about this one, any hints on how to go about this one?

$$D = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 & 3\\0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Let:
$$T(\vec x) = D \vec x$$

Compute:

$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}3 \\0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

[*Image of problem*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B2Ss.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please make sure I edited your question properly. It really helps readability to format questions using Mathjax (see FAQ). Also, it helps to show responders what your thoughts and what you have tried. If this is HW, it should be tagged as such. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $T$ is a linear transformation and $D$ is the matrix associated to $T$ in a certain base. Then

$$
T\left(\left[ \begin{matrix}
3\\
0\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right]\right) =
\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & 4 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
3\\
0\\
-1
\end{matrix}\right] =
\left[\begin{matrix}
3\\
0\\
2
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Comment: is it possible for you to explain how the calculations are done?

Comment: Figured out it's: 2 * 3 + 2 * 0 + 2 * -1 = 3, 0 * 3 + 0 * 0 + 0 * -1 = 0, 1 * 3 + 3 * 0 + 1 * -1 = 2

Comment: 2*3 + 4*0 + 3*(-1) = 3<br/>
0*3 + 1*0 + 0*(-1) = 0
1*3 + 3*0 + 1*(-1) = 2

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want to concentrate on understanding exactly what T(x) = Dx means with regard to linear transformations and matrices. If you fully understand that, I think the answer will be clear. (Hopefully I'm not missing something deep here.)

A linear transformation (or linear map) from (vector space) V to (vector space) W is a function T:V->W which satisfies some properties making it linear. Both vectors and linear transformations can be represented by matrices. I would expect this to be in any introductory linear algebra text, but I happen to have Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right".